# Need help amending macro to use one Internet Explorer Window

Tags: excel, performance, web-scraping, vba

The below function opens Oanda.com and takes the currency conversion rate between USD and a input (another currency). The equation will be filled down with another macro to span 48 rows. The macro as it stands, will open 48 Internet Explorer Windows and close them after extracting the data point (1 at a time as the equation updates down the column). This process is tedious and the below method seems to be more efficient on every front but I cannot figure out how to implement:

Is there a way to amend this to first check for existing Internet Explorer window, If one is open, simply use that window to go to the domain (which is variable here) and extract data. If a window is not open, then open one. I do not know procedures to search for programs running in the background.

The main goal is to speed up the equation when it is executed by fill down. Any suggestions welcome.

Clarity Edit: I created the UDF to help me build a table. Currency tickers (USD, EUR, GBP, etc) will span Column A down to row 48. Column B needs to show the corresponding conversion rate matched against 1 USD (down to row 48). The UDF below does as intended but i'm seeking an alternative, more efficient, way to do this.

Option Explicit

```
Public Function ConvertUSD(ConvertWhat As String) As Double

    'References
    '   Microsoft XML, vs.0
    '   Microsoft Internet Controls
    '   Microsoft HTML Object Library.

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    'IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter?quote_currency=USD&base_currency=" & ConvertWhat

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = ReadyState_Complete
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.Document
    Dim Ans As String
    Ans = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innerText)
    Dim AnsExtract As Variant
    AnsExtract = Split(Ans, " ")

    ConvertUSD = AnsExtract(4)

    IE.Quit

End Function
```

Comment: I know this ends with "IE.Quit" but that is because I cannot get the other method to work. If this wasnt added, I would have 48 IE windows open in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub MainSub()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    '
    Dim x As Long
    Dim Currencies As Variant
    Currencies = Array("GBP", "EUR", "JPY", "HKD")
    '
    For x = LBound(Currencies) To UBound(Currencies)
        Debug.Print "1 USD = " & ConvertUSD(Currencies(x), IE) & " " & Currencies(x)
    Next x
    IE.Quit ' Quit here instead
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function ConvertUSD(ByVal ConvertWhat As String, IE As InternetExplorer) As Double

    'References
    '   Microsoft XML, vs.0
    '   Microsoft Internet Controls
    '   Microsoft HTML Object Library.

    ' Dim IE As New InternetExplorer ' Commented out here

    IE.Navigate "https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter?quote_currency=USD&base_currency=" & ConvertWhat

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = ReadyState_Complete
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.Document
    Dim Ans As String
    Ans = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(2).innerText)
    Dim AnsExtract As Variant
    AnsExtract = Split(Ans, " ")

    ConvertUSD = AnsExtract(4)

    ' IE.Quit ' Don't quit here

End Function
```

Your problem is that you keep opening a new IE every time the function is called. However if you open one before calling the function, you'll be able to re-use it as needed - and only quit after you've finished.

Comment: The input format (ConvertWhat) is currency tickers: For example, USD, EUR, GBP, HKD, etc. Only one input of course. Also, if for whatever reason, you wanted ConvertUSD(USD), the answer would be 1.

Comment: So there’s no “amount” argument then? You’re not looking to convert a variable amount, but just get the exchange rate of 1 of the source currency?

Comment: Yes, we are just extracting the conversion rate out of Oanda (which will always be compared to 1 USD).

Comment: I have also not figured out how to mod the date input by using the domain. That is an issue for another question most likely though. The date needs to be (Date -1) i.e. Yesterday

Comment: Okay - answer edited to show a range of different currencies in a loop. Tested and working.

Comment: I added both of these to a module. Cell A1 = EUR, Cell B2 = ConvertUSD(A1) and im getting a #VALUE!. I should run the first module, and then use the equation right?

Comment: Seems like you want a dynamic UDF? That won’t work with the modified code I provided, as the IE object won’t’ve been created, and there’s no second argument provided in your funtion caller. Perhaps you’d better edit your original question to flesh out exactly how you want to use this function. Tip: UDFs trying to open a new IE is a very bad idea!

Comment: I need to build a simple table. Column A will be a list of currency tickers (48) and column B needs to be the corresponding conversion rate matched to 1 USD. My initial plan was to put my UDF in cell B2 (row 1 is headers naturally) and then filldown the UDF to B48. Your tip is definitely valid, which is why I am here seeking an alternative!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171652/discussion-between-urdearboy-and-chris-melville).

Comment: @urdearboy - what you're asking is beyond the scope of your original question. Your question related to being able to use the same IE, instead of having to open lots of them. That question has been answered (and I'd very much appreciate an up-vote and a tick if you are satisfied). Regarding your other issue, you need to raise a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Valid ask. I will create a new question now with the same tags. Hope to see you there!